# How to get position with XPath?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

Let's say I have this HTML structure:

```
<table> 
  <tr>...</tr>  
  <tr>...</tr>  
  <tr> 
    <td>111</td> 
  </tr>  
  <tr> 
    <td>222</td> 
  </tr> 
</table>
```

What will be right XPath if I need to find number of `<tr>` tags from first `<tr>` to `<tr>` tag which has `/td[text()='111']`

In my example number of `<tr>` tags will be 3.

And result will be 4 if we want to see number of `<tr>` from beginning to `<tr>` which has `"/td[@text='222']"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath

```
count(//tr[td ='111']/preceding-sibling::tr) + 1
```

applied against this markup

```
<table> 
  <tr>...</tr>  
  <tr>...</tr>  
  <tr> 
    <td>111</td> 
  </tr>  
  <tr> 
    <td>222</td> 
  </tr> 
</table>
```

will return

```
3
```

as requested.